# "unsupported operand type" error in numpy.corrcoef on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have been trying to get correlation between dataframes with `numpy`, but I'm stuck with error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

is there any wrong with my code, or what should I add? thank you

```
import pandas as pd

usd = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")
emas = pd.read_csv("emas_.csv")
minyak = pd.read_csv("minyak_brent.csv")
sawit = pd.read_csv("sawit.csv")
kcl = pd.read_csv("kcl.csv")
fosfat = pd.read_csv("fosfat.csv")


df1 = pd.DataFrame(usd)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(emas)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(minyak)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(sawit)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(kcl)
df6 = pd.DataFrame(fosfat)
df_col = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6], axis=1)
df_col.columns
df_col = df_col.set_index('month')
df_col.head()
import numpy as np
np.corrcoef(df_col)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your dataframe, it seems like you have columns that contain strings- not just numbers. `np.corrcoef` doesn't know what to do when you want to correlate an array of number with an array strings.

Sample data (note that column D contains strings of numbers that we will convert to a proper numeric dtype):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [1,2,3,4,5], 
     "B":[2,9,21,30,100], 
     "C":list("abcde"), 
     "D": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}
)

print(df.dtypes)
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
D    object
dtype: object

print(df)
   A    B  C  D
0  1    2  a  1
1  2    9  b  2
2  3   21  c  3
3  4   30  d  4
4  5  100  e  5
```

Convert columns to numeric if possible:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")

print(df.dtypes)
A     int64
B     int64
C    object
D     int64
dtype: object
```

Use `np.corrcoef` on the numeric columns.

```
np.corrcoef(df.select_dtypes("number"), rowvar=False)

array([[1.        , 0.87309983, 1.        ],
       [0.87309983, 1.        , 0.87309983],
       [1.        , 0.87309983, 1.        ]])
```

Alternatively, if you know your columns are all their intended dtype. You can just use the `DataFrame.corr()` method without having to select the numeric columns like you do with `np.corrcoef`

```
df.corr()

        A       B       D
A  1.0000  0.8731  1.0000
B  0.8731  1.0000  0.8731
D  1.0000  0.8731  1.0000
```